# Scala insert new key to every element of List[Map[String,Double]]

Tags: scala

I have a list of map as shown below.

```
val data = List(
    Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0), Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 40.0, "d" -> 2.0), Map("a" -> 4.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0), Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 90.0, "d" -> 17.0)
)
```

I want to insert one key to every map (element) in a list.

say key is "k" and value is 1

So , result should look like

```
 List(Map(a -> 1.0, b -> 267.0, c -> 26.0, k -> 1, d -> 2.0), Map(a -> 1.0, b -> 2678.0, c -> 40.0, k -> 1, d -> 2.0), Map(a -> 4.0, b -> 267.0, c -> 26.0, k -> 1, d -> 2.0), Map(a -> 1.0, b -> 2678.0, c -> 90.0, k -> 1, d -> 17.0))
```

I used the below code to get the same result

```
var result:List[Map[String,Double]] = List.empty
result = result ::: data(key).map(x=>x.++(Map("k"->1)))
```

But it is consuming too much time.. some 300ms for 100k elements in a list

Is there any other efficient way to do this. Ideal time consumption should be 0.

Comment: Did you try using the parallel call on the collection? Some reference here: http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-8-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-collection-functions/scala-par-example/

Comment: why are you concatenating an empty list to the one you want to operate with?? In your example your usage of `:::` is redundant.

Comment: It would be O(1) only if you used mutable data structure - if you want to insert things in all maps, then you are creating a modified copy of each map (depending on implementation, that might be small O, though) and then you are creating a new list of copies (O(n) of the size of List). Also you might consider pair addition instead of map concatenation: `data.map(_ + ("k" -> 1))`

Comment: Besides, how do you benchmark? JMH or cold VM?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fast enough:

```
  val m = (1 to 1000).map(_.toString).zipWithIndex.toMap // Map(710 -> 709, 205 -> 204, 45 -> 44, ...

  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val l2 = (1 to 2000).map(_ => m) // List(Map(a -> 1.0, b -> 267.0, c -> 26.0, ...

  val r =   l2.map(_ + ("z" -> 2))
  println(s"${r.length} maps of ${r.head.size} took ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} ms")
```

This prints: *2000 maps of 1001 took 5 ms*